# Expand one table-cell only

Tags: html, css

I have two table cells, with dynamic content.

Table cell one works fine, when new content is added to it making it bigger than table cell 2, table cell 2's height fits table cell 1's and all is well in the universe.

But when new content is added to table cell 2 (which has overflow hidden, and works fine with display: block) it expands, the overflow never happens, and table cell 1's height now matches table cell 2.

What I want is when more content is added to table cell 2, it will show content up to table cell 1, then the rest is hidden. I understand I can do it in javascript, any idea how to do it without it?

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dYsNx/

Col 2 should only go up to col1's height in content, rest should be overflow hidden

Comment: Did you make cell 2 be fixed-width? table cells will naturally grow to fit their contents, unless you fix their size.

Comment: Can you show some code? Or a JSFiddle? I mean, I am not able to correctly understand your problem. Is that you want a `colspan` or `rowspan`?

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/dYsNx/ - Col 2 should only go up to col1's height in content, rest should be overflow hidden

Comment: @MarcB is right .. you need to set the height to what you want column 1 to be ..

Comment: Column 1's height changes, it's not fixed. I just want column 1 to be the parent, and column 2 to be the child that only matches the parent's height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

overflow: hidden should not be used in that way.
But, you get the concept.

Others, I saw your code is not very clean and keeping in standard.
So, I would modify it in my way (hope it is better)

Please see the following link:
http://jsfiddle.net/Edditoria/TGfzA/

As you see, `overflow: hidden;` is in `#box`, then set `position: relative;` without top/left setting.

To avoid display:table compatibility issue of IE<7, please just keep the default div display setting in CSS. I would use % rather than fixed px width to avoid IE's display issues too!

Assuming col1 is the base of dynamic height, there's nothing to do.

In col2 (and all other columns), you will need to add `position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 50%;`.

I change the col-x from ID to class, since you may need to add more columns later.

- update: base on your comment, added scrolling instead of hide extra information.

Comment: Sorry about the code, I just wrote it from scratch in JSFiddle w/o code hints and all that other glorious stuff, since my code was a bit more complex to copy and paste (but standard compliant ;] ). - It would be perfect, except I forgot to mention that the overflow was supposed to show a y scroll bar, like: overflow-y: scroll; - but when I apply it, the scroll bar gets cut off. - I think i'll just keep the second column an inline-block of fixed height, it seems less problematic.

Comment: LOL, I do write mess codes without hints too. And I'm bad in English. I try to figure it out. Would you please click the link to see again? The y-scroll bar will appear only if needed (auto) instead of hide the extra information exceed the height. All you need to do is add `height: 100%;`

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible by means of pure CSS. This is from CSS 2.1 spec ( http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#height-layout ):

**In CSS 2.1, the height of a cell box is the minimum height required by the content.**

**The height of a 'table-row' element's box** is calculated once the user agent has all the cells in the row available: it **is the maximum of the row's computed 'height', the computed 'height' of each cell in the row, and the minimum height (MIN) required by the cells.**